# How can I easily export content from Sitecore 6?

Tags: export, sitecore, sitecore6

I need to find a simple way to export Sitecore 6 content to a file for translation.  I tried using Control Panel | Globalization | Export Languages to a File.  However I get odd results.  For some reason it seems like it is only exporting the __Source field and no other fields.  So the XML file that I get back isn't very helpful - it doesn't include all of the fields in the content item.

Does anyone know how I can either get the Export Languages feature to work properly or if there is some other easy way to export content from Sitecore 6?

Comment: Did you have any luck? Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I found out that the problem I was facing was because of cloning in Sitecore.  If a content item is a clone then it is not exported via the Export Languages feature unless the field has been modified from the source.  So the answer is to just do translation on the source items and then when they are re-imported, accept the cloning notifications and the content will all be translated properly.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize the content item

1. Navigate to the item in the Content Editor
2. Select the "Developer" tab at the top
3. Hit "Serialize Item" in the "Serialize" chunk
4. Navigate to your /data/serialization/itempath such as... "/data/serialization/master/sitecore/content/home.item"
5. There's your file

Now that you've made edits to the file for localization

1. Overwrite the file in serialization step #4 with new copy
2. Navigate to the item in the Content Editor
3. Select the "Developer" tab at the top
4. Hit "Update Item" in the "Serialize" chunk
5. You're all done

You can fully export a database using the serialization admin tool at http://yoursite.com/sitecore/admin/serialization.aspx